# Error while installing django version 1.7.1 using pip

Tags: python, django, installation, pip, django-1.7

Obtained the following code through `pip install django==1.7.1`

```
Downloading/unpacking django==1.7.1­­
Downloading Django-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4MB): 7.4MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: django
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 279, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1380, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 664, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 894, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 202, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 189, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/hansonzihanzeng/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
sudo pip install django==1.7.1
```

You got a `Permission Denied` error, that means the process can't write to the directory because it doesn't have enough privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **sudo** to allow permissions to write it.

`sudo pip install django==1.7.1`

If however you want to install it on Python3 (3.x), you'll have to use **pip3**

`sudo pip3 install django==1.7.1`

However if you give yourself root priviledges in the terminal you don't have to use sudo.
You get root by using the `sudo su` command and entering your password. Once that is done, any actions taken  in that window are considered to have root permission. However this is generally not good practice.